# Angular $watch not working, unless I click some were on the screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Am using angular $watch such as.

Based on a trigger selectedIndex value changes.

```
 $scope.selectedIndex = 1;
   Trigger.onReceivingTriger($scope,function(data){
         $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
    });


    $scope.$watch('selectedIndex', function(){
        console.log("am watching");
    });
```

I expect to work as once the trigger value set the watch should work as normal. But the problem is the $watch works only after I click some were on the screen. 
I got stuck hear...
any help please....

Comment: Typo in onReceivingTriger maybe? Should be onReceivingTrigger. Just a guess.

Comment: Its just a function name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run digest cycle as you are updating scope outside of angular, using event. You need to digest cycle by doing `$scope.$apply()`

**Code**

```
Trigger.onReceivingTriger($scope,function(data){
     $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
     $scope.$apply();
});
```